# To get current Instance of the session scoped bean in Jsf 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

i referred to this question  and i've a similar problem 
[JSF - Get the SessionScoped Bean instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278861/jsf-get-the-sessionscoped-bean-instance)

I want to get the current instance of a managed bean in another managed bean. I've a SuperBean which is extended in a base Class - baseBean.
I set the value of a list - itemList in baseBean. The getter setter of the list are in SuperBean and I should use this SuperBean in my BackingBean to get the value of the itemList.

I tried using -

```
     Application app = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
      ValueBinding vb = app.createValueBinding("#{superbean}");
      SuperClass superclass = (SuperClass) vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
```

When I try to print superclass.getItems(); - It gives only this - []

And also this -

```
  SuperClass superclass = (SuperClass)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                         getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("superbean");
```

When I try to print with this - It throws exception as my superbean entry is not present in the sessionMap even though the entry is placed in facesConfig and also as @ManagedBean and @sessionscoped

Kindly help me resolve this.

Comment: Doesn't the solution of the referred question help? I think you won't need the SuperBean if you use the `@ManagedProperty` annotation. I think your superbean won't be intantiated if you only reference properties from sub classes.

Comment: @ManagedProperty annotation has to be given in my BackingBean is it?

Comment: Added an answer with an example

Comment: You need to concentrate on the problem why it returns an empty list, not on how you grab it from the context. Using `@ManagedProperty` should be perfectly fine. Perhaps you've just created a completely different instance manually?

Comment: @BalusC Congratulations for hitting the 200k!

Comment: @MattHandy: thank you :) It's still below 200,000 though. It's just rounded up from half K.

Comment: @BalusC It's a question of hours ... ;-)

Comment: @MattHandy: or 2 days ;) I've already hit the rep cap today. I have only 400 to go. I don't think that I will get another 25 accepted answers today ;) Tomorrow (in weekend) I don't think I will go over 400 as well, maybe 200~300. It'll be sunday.

Comment: @BalusC I tried fetching the instance from the SessionMap. But my question is, Why are the bean entries present in the map?

Comment: Where else should JSF store session scoped beans, do you think? (assuming that you know the basic Servlet API well)

Comment: I'm new to JSF and Servlets. I thought when the scope of the bean is made session and present in the faces context, it can be retrieved through the sessionMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject a managed bean into another if the injected bean has the same or broader scope. Here is an example:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "oneBean")
@ViewScoped
public class OneBean{
    // injections
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{anotherBean}")
    private AnotherBean anotherBean;

    // don't forget to add getter and setter for anotherBean
    ...
}
```