# Why is this @SessionScoped class getting recreated so often?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

I have a `@SessionScoped` class that holds a private variable. I noticed that if I left the browser tab alone for about 5-10 seconds and then refreshed, the private variable was null. So i put a `System.out.println` in the constructor and I see it's being created multiple times!

Why is this happening?

```
package com.test;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@SessionScoped
public class TestSessionScoped implements Serializable
{
    @Inject
    private MyOtherClass injectedOther;

    public TestSessionScoped()
    {
        System.out.println( "CREATED TestSessionScoped.class in Session Scope" );
    }

    private int userid = 0;

    //Simplified to test setting the variable
    public void login()
    {
        userid = 1;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        version="3.1">
<display-name>DI API</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- CDI listener (Used by events) -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- CDI Bean Manager for injecting events -->
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: In `TestSessionScoped` bean use `@PostConstruct` listener to access injected `MyOtherClass `  after bean's construction. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4278905/6743203

Comment: @JaySmith The injected `MyOtherClass` is not the issue. The issue is `userid`. Since I get a different instance of the `TestSessionScoped` every time (in my servlet which injects `TestSessionScoped`), the userid is 0. Also, this is CDI, not JSF.